# What is grails wrapper directory for?

Tags: java, grails, dependencies

I created an app using create-app with Grails 2.3.7, I noticed there is a wrapper directory with jars inside.

Isn't the dependecies are handled by maven(.m2) or ivy?

What is it for? Why is it located inside the grails application and should I include it under version control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Grails Wrapper**

The Grails Wrapper allows a **Grails** application to build without having to install Grails and configure a **GRAILS_HOME** environment variable. The wrapper includes a small shell script and a couple of small bootstrap jar files that typically would be checked in to source code control along with the rest of the project.

The first time the wrapper is executed it will download and configure a Grails installation. This wrapper makes it more simple to setup a development environment, configure CI and manage upgrades to future versions of Grails. When the application is upgraded to the next version of Grails, the wrapper is updated and checked in to the source code control system and the next time developers update their workspace and run the wrapper, they will automatically be using the correct version of Grails.[Taken from](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#wrapper)
See the [Wrapper Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#wrapper) for more details.

And [see this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140725204434/http://java.dzone.com/articles/grails-goodness-using-wrapper)

But on Grails 2.3.7 there is no shell script for wrapper is described above , but the jar that need to run GRAILS without installing are insalled by default

```
asm-3.2.jar
asm-tree-3.2.jar
grails-wrapper-runtime-2.3.7.jar
grails-wrapper.properties
springloaded-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: I am using grails 2.1.1 version it did not created the wrapper and is it mandatory the wrapper folder in present new versions

Comment: ok thank you is it mandatory to place in our project directory , what is the purpose of  grailsw ,is grailsw is mandatory to use

Comment: Is it advisable to commit this file or the folder into source code repository?

Comment: If the purpose of this folder is to allow an application to build without having grails, then I would say yes